# Printing data file containing multiple matrixes

Tags: java, arrays, loops, matrix

I'm running into a problem with a program that I'm writing for a class.
I was given a text file that contains three matrices and I need to create a loop that prints out all three of them in the output through various filters.

Here is what the file contains:

```
15 15

91 114 75 145 149 250 31 103 88 123 27 120 187 140 52 
108 23 43 126 51 9 107 29 20 221 18 41 178 245 159 
187 53 7 107 96 82 70 2 171 2 36 84 135 187 92 
176 30 199 230 178 61 48 211 208 143 178 207 79 196 217 
26 6 117 170 4 245 63 93 108 44 163 19 6 220 131 
7 210 228 154 213 96 102 254 63 34 25 215 168 23 207 
131 254 198 215 164 6 141 150 147 26 242 199 237 131 240 
102 22 248 74 26 3 138 145 132 120 97 126 8 86 166 
178 68 73 127 56 180 182 152 3 149 184 42 204 9 172 
104 203 99 132 204 137 33 69 140 19 131 38 239 56 180 
163 249 88 222 98 150 58 155 115 188 70 189 162 33 1 
113 141 52 196 139 241 68 37 89 215 166 7 200 179 26 
21 68 167 53 226 167 193 232 133 79 212 163 101 157 233 
122 17 114 224 129 247 35 84 120 51 91 149 127 150 19 
217 253 145 45 205 179 107 76 214 48 230 218 8 135 25 

6 6

201 159 87 63 240 244 
231 32 222 76 5 255 
10 5 248 139 47 64 
167 76 138 177 107 159 
188 122 154 165 205 22 
222 149 148 85 129 57 

5 5

201 159 87 63 240  
231 32 222 76 5  
10 5 248 139 47 
167 76 138 177 107 
188 122 154 165 205
```

I was able to get a loop that read the file and prints out the first 15x15 array, but I need a loop that will print out the other three after it including the filters applied to the data.

That is:

```
Base image data:
(15x15 array)
(6x6 array)
(5x5 array)
Filtered data:
(15x15 filtered)
(6x6 filtered)
(5x5 filtered)
```

I'm able to print out the first array just fine, but I am racking my brain trying to find a way to loop the code to print out the other two arrays. Additionally, I have a second problem that when the filtered data is printed, it's all 0s like so:

```
Base Image Data
91 114 75 145 149 250 31 103 88 123 27 120 187 140 52
108 23 43 126 51 9 107 29 20 221 18 41 178 245 159
187 53 7 107 96 82 70 2 171 2 36 84 135 187 92
176 30 199 230 178 61 48 211 208 143 178 207 79 196 217
26 6 117 170 4 245 63 93 108 44 163 19 6 220 131
7 210 228 154 213 96 102 254 63 34 25 215 168 23 207
131 254 198 215 164 6 141 150 147 26 242 199 237 131 240
102 22 248 74 26 3 138 145 132 120 97 126 8 86 166
178 68 73 127 56 180 182 152 3 149 184 42 204 9 172
104 203 99 132 204 137 33 69 140 19 131 38 239 56 180
163 249 88 222 98 150 58 155 115 188 70 189 162 33 1
113 141 52 196 139 241 68 37 89 215 166 7 200 179 26
21 68 167 53 226 167 193 232 133 79 212 163 101 157 233
122 17 114 224 129 247 35 84 120 51 91 149 127 150 19
217 253 145 45 205 179 107 76 214 48 230 218 8 135 25
Image Filter1:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The code I have it pretty extensive, so I'm having trouble pinpointing why it's returning 0s.

Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("imagedata.txt"));

    int r = scanner.nextInt();
    int c = scanner.nextInt();
    int [][] imageData = new int[r][c];
    //for loop to create 2d array from image data
    for(int row=0; row<imageData.length; row++) {
        for(int col=0; col<imageData[row].length; col++) {
            imageData[row][col] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Base Image Data");
    for(int[] row : imageData) {
        for(int num : row) {
            System.out.print(num+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("Image Filter1:");

    int[][] filter1 = applyFilter1(imageData);//call return from applyFilter1
    for(int[] row : filter1){
        for(int num : row){
            System.out.print(num+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static int[][] applyFilter1(int[][] imageData){
    int[][] filtered = new int[imageData.length][imageData[0].length];

    for (int row=0; row<filtered.length;row++){
        for (int col=0;col<filtered[row].length;col++){
            int[] nebs = getNeighbors(row, col, imageData);
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<nebs.length; i++){
                sum = sum + nebs[i];
                int average = sum / nebs.length;
                filtered[row][col] = average;
            }
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}

public static int[] getNeighbors(int row, int col, int[][] imageData){
    //find neighbors of current index
    int [][] copyImage = new int[imageData.length][imageData[0].length];
    try{
        for(int r=0; r<imageData.length; r++){
            for(int c=0; c<imageData[r].length; c++){
                imageData[r][c] = copyImage[r][c];
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Array copy not successful");
    }

    //handles the top row of the array
    if(row==0){//if copyImage[0].length
        if(col==0){//handles upper left corner of array
            int[] nebs = {copyImage[row][col], copyImage[row+1][col],
                    copyImage[row][col+1]};
            return nebs;
        }
        else if(col==copyImage[row].length-1){//handles upper right corner of array
            int[] nebs = {copyImage[row][col], copyImage[row][col-1],
                    copyImage[row+1][col]};
            return nebs;
        }
        else{//handles top row of array between corners
            int[] nebs = {copyImage[row][col], copyImage[row][col-1],
                    copyImage[row+1][col], copyImage[row][col+1]};
            return nebs;
        }
    }
    //handles the bottom row of the array
    else if(row==copyImage.length-1){//if the row is at max value
        if(col==0){//handles botton left corner of array
            int[] nebs = {copyImage[row][col], copyImage[row-1][col],
                    copyImage[row][col+1]};
            return nebs;
        }
        else if(col==copyImage[row].length-1){//handles bottom right corner of array
            int[] nebs = {copyImage[row][col], copyImage[row-1][col],
                    copyImage[row][col-1]};
            return nebs;
        }
        else{//handles bottom row of array
            int[] nebs = {copyImage[row][col], copyImage[row-1][col],
                    copyImage[row][col-1], copyImage[row][col+1]};
            return nebs;
        }
    }
    //handles leftmost column of array
    else if(col==0){//if col=0 and row increases
        int[] nebs = {copyImage[row][col], copyImage[row-1][col],
                copyImage[row+1][col], copyImage[row][col+1]};
        return nebs;
    }
    //handles rightmost column of array
    else if(col==copyImage[row].length-1){//if col=max value and row increases
        int[] nebs = {copyImage[row][col], copyImage[row-1][col],
                copyImage[row+1][col], copyImage[row][col-1]};
        return nebs;
    }
    //handles values in the body of the array
    else{
        int[] nebs = {copyImage[row][col], copyImage[row-1][col],
                copyImage[row+1][col], copyImage[row][col-1],
                copyImage[row][col+1]};
        return nebs;
    }
}
```

I'm still new to java, despite the amount of code in this program. So any guidance and feedback is welcome.

Comment: have you tried reading line by line? that would make parsing the file easier. Using the split() method for strings and knowing the size of those arrays would making parsing a bit easier

Comment: Normally, that would be a great option, however, my program requires that I create a loop that can apply for all 2D arrays. My professor will be testing it with different files containing different number of arrays, so unfortunately I don't know the size of the unknown arrays.

Comment: you would know the size of the arrays, the first line before the array tells you the dimensions of the array 15x15, 6x6, 5x5 and so on. I'm sure the files he tests will use that format where the line in the file that has two numbers will be the dimensions of the array

Comment: if you read line by line, splitting the line around a space character and checking the size returned would let you know what you are looking at. If the size of split is 0, you have an empty line and can continue, if the array after split is 2 then you know you have a new array to parse, and the variable sizes can be assumed to be a part of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply read this file line-by-line, split each string into an array of numbers, then format them as a *three-character string*, concatenate them back and output. No matter how many matrices are in this file.

```java
List<String> list = List.of(
        "91 114 75 145 149 250 31 103 88 123 27 120 187 140 52",
        "108 23 43 126 51 9 107 29 20 221 18 41 178 245 159",
        "187 53 7 107 96 82 70 2 171 2 36 84 135 187 92");

list.stream()
        .map(str -> Arrays
                // split string into an array of numbers
                .stream(str.split("\s+"))
                // format as a three-character string
                .map(s -> String.format("%3s", s))
                // concatenate into a single string
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
        // output line by line
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
 91 114  75 145 149 250  31 103  88 123  27 120 187 140  52
108  23  43 126  51   9 107  29  20 221  18  41 178 245 159
187  53   7 107  96  82  70   2 171   2  36  84 135 187  92
```